# Search approach for web site content

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, search, indexing

I have been looking for a search approach the implement on my web site, however I have not been able to decide the best approach. The content that can be searched in is placed in six different tables. One table containing “tags” one with “categories” and then four tables each containing a title column.

I have been looking into pure sql searches, but it seems a bit slow (I can not use full text search index) and furthermore I want the search to find results with words similar to the words that are search for and not just “total matches” e.g. the search for a miss spelled word "Memhis" should also return the content with "Memphis".

Which approach will you take and what algorithms / data structures are good for the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) seems very popular for website search, and I think it can do all that fuzzy matching stuff.  It doesn't need SQL full-text search.

Comment: I have been looking at Lucene.NET but i have not yet found some documentation about keeping the index in memory and how to handle changes in the database / rebuilding the index?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not strictly after an embedded solution, I'd recommend [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). Simply put, it exposes Lucene over HTTP. We have started with Lucene.Net but it didn't take too long for us to switch to Solr. It is written in java but you won't need to write any java code.

One can use [DIH](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) (I haven't used it) or [Solrnet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/) (one we're using) with c#/.Net to get the job done.

About index (re)generation; it can be as simple as regenerating the index once or twice a day or combined with triggers etc. updating individual entries, or a combination of the two.

It can be a steep learning curve but I'd say it's well worth the time if you can spare some.

Answer (score 0):

I would create another Table Column that concatenate all the different columns, then run search on it. This is how I done my on my site. To find similar words, there should be existing plugin to do it. You shouldn't be doing it yourself.